# How to initialize an instance variable in constructor of child class, from an instance variable of parent class in Dart

Tags: dart

Please consider these parent and child classes of Java and see how `calculationDao` has been initialized in `CalculationRepository` on the basis of instance variable `db` of parent class `SqliteRepository` :

**Parent class:**

```
public class SqliteRepository {

    final MyDatabase db;

    public SqliteRepository(@NonNull Application application) {
        db = MyDatabase.get(application);
    }
}
```

**Child class:**

```
public class CalculationRepository extends SqliteRepository {

    private final CalculationDao calculationDao;

    public CalculationRepository(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        calculationDao = db.calculationDao();
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the same thing in Dart. Here are the Dart classes:

**Parent class:**

```
class SqliteRepository {
    final MyDatabase db;

    SqliteRepository({required BuildContext context}) : db = MyDatabase.instance;

}
```

**Child class:**

```
class CalculationRepository extends SqliteRepository {
    final CalculationDao _calculationDao;
    
    CalculationRepository({required super.context}) : _calculationDao = db.calculationDao;

}
```

However, this gives the following error:

`The instance member 'db' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)`

`Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution but in vain.

Could anyone please guide me how I can initialize this final variable `calculationDao` in the constructor of `CalculationRepository`?

Any help would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `db` inside the constructor itself. But since you're not specifying the value of the `final` property `_calculationDao` at the time of initialization, you can mark it with `late`:

```dart
class CalculationRepository extends SqliteRepository {
  late final CalculationDao _calculationDao;

  CalculationViewModel({required super.context}) {
    _calculationDao = db.calculationDao;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Following your lead, I came across this nice article on `late` keyword: https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/03/flutter-lazy-instantiation-with-the-late-keyword.html just to realize that I can also initialize the variable as `late final CalculationDao _calculationDao = db.calculationDao;` and keep the constructor intact as `CalculationViewModel({required super.context});`. Before that, I considered using `late` as something extremely risky and prone to errors.